# Should he apply to job after getting fired in same company(after a time)

Tags: professionalism, management, hiring-process, recruitment, applications

Yesterday, I met one of my friends. He was discussing about his first employer. He told me that his employer had fired him 8-10 months ago. Now, my friend wants to apply again there. He has discussed that company is nearest from his home.

I asked the reason of fired, he told me that some conflict with his senior. I advised him to not go there, because they may reject you. However, I have not enough experience in such case.

> What do you give advise him? Should he apply there?

Comment: Does an application hurt? No. Is he likely to get the job? Also no.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, I'll discuss this.

Comment: I had a shitty job in a call center for a bank when I was 19 and eventually got fired for goofing off because every single second of that job was a soul-destroying nightmare that crushed my will to live and literally made me ill.  I applied for a job with the same company 15 years later as a senior software developer and was offered the job (but ended up accepting a different offer).  Nobody seemed to mind that I'd worked there previously and it hadn't ended well.  There's a big difference between being a low-level expendable barely-human grunt and a skilled professional with market value.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom, good. Inspiring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is hardly any harm in applying again. But there is no point, not really.

If he was fired justly, they have his records and usually his application will go straight into shredder. There is some chance if it is a low income, low skill job no one really wants anyway. In such situations employer may don't care that much and allow him in, but there is a huge chance of meeting the same senior and getting fired again.

If he was fired unjustly and can prove it, he would have a better chance in court than in second application process. And he shouldn't really want to work for such employer anyway.

> company is nearest from his home.

And this is just terrible reasoning. I don't think he treats getting a job seriously. Commute can be bad, but it's not worth wasting your live in a bad job to save few minutes of commute. Also, applying to just one place (that's what I *guess* he is doing)? That's not a way to find a place for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would say if he needs a job and there is a opening that he has the skills for, why not apply?  People move in and out of positions over a career with a company, so who knows what the results would be.  ( Example: in the case that the HR regime has changed )

Having said that, I think the odds are not in their favor as most HR organizations keep records for up to 7 years, and also have a flag in whatever HR system they have that basically asks "Would you hire this person again?"